# Dynamic Query in Spring Data

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I build a native query dynamically on a class especific, and I need to pass this query to JpaRepository to execute it. The result is all the same. I don't know if this is possible, but is it only solution for my problem.

An example:

```
@Component
public class DataCmd {
    public List<IncomingDataDTO> getAllIncomingData(String dynamicQuery){
        entity = this.getIncomingDataRepository().findAllByQuery(dynamicQuery);
    }
}


@Repository
public interface IncomingDataRepository extends JpaRepository<IncomingData, IncomingDataPK> {
    @Query(dynamicQuery)
    public List<IncomingData> findAllByQuery();
}
```

Comment: Create a [custom repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and run your custom query using criteria builder.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass parameters to the annotation at run-time and are trying to invoke the method of the repository with a query parameter, but it isn't defined.

Executing SQL requests directly is a bad idea, you'd better wrote your query something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE a = :id")
public List<IncomingData> findAllByQuery(@Param("id") long id);
```

Or if you want to construct the query dynamically, you may use Spring Data's `Specification` or use `QueryDSL` library. More info in [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Answer (score 0):

You can `@Autowire EntityManager` and execute plain `SQL` using it. This does not require `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Autowire EntityManager em;
```

in your **DataCmd** and then query your data via

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql, IncomingData.class);
return q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I don't need add any method in IncomingDataRepository?

Comment: No, you just need the `EntityManager` to create queries :) 
Though it's more clean to use Repositories if there is no need for "dynamic" sql